# Spring boot MultipartFile transferTo not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-io, multipartfile

The line `file1.createNewFile();` creates a new file, but the `file.transferTo(file1);` does not transfer the contents of the MultipartFile to file1.
Is there a way to make the `transferTo` method work?

```
@PostMapping("/form3")
public String handleFormUpload3(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
    File file1 = new File(fileName);
    if(!file1.exists())
        file1.createNewFile();
    file.transferTo(file1);
    System.out.println(file1.exists());
    return "redirect:uploadSuccess";
}
```

When I use `FileOutputStream` to save the MultipartFile to a regular file by converting into to a byte array, the transfer works fine. But `transferTo()` is much simpler and less verbose. How do I make it work?

Comment: Where do you expect to see your file? I can see you have created new File without any path, and `getOrifinalFileName` is not going to give you a file path, make sure you knew where the current directory is.

Comment: @Popeye. The file does get created as mentioned in the outermost folder in the project. The issue I face is that the `transferTo()` does not work in my code.

I saw your other comment that it worked for you. Please let me know if the exact same code worked?

Comment: The exact code you have written. Please be more specific on how it does not work, Does it throw exception? Is it just no files are created?

Comment: Give an absolute path, if you use `File`  the renamed file got created in `ROOT` directory of `TOMCAT`, I can explain the reason, but then I will have to offer a complete answer.

Comment: The code gets executed successfully without throwing any exceptions. File gets created thanks to `createNewFile()` But the MultipartFile did not get transferred to the file.

Comment: As I said in my last comment , if you do not provide absolute path , your code will not execute properly. In production environment it will start writing file in your home directory, worse case, somewhere where it won't even have permission to write. Also creating file before moving is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

I have reproduced your case and can confirm that `transferTo()` with `File` object doesn't work. I don't know why. But `transferTo()` with `Path` works fine.

This code works fine:

```
String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
File file1 = new File(fileName);
file.transferTo(file1.toPath());
```

EDIT: I have checked the source code (Java 20) and there is an obvious difference between (1) transferTo(File file) and (2) transferTo(Path path): in (1) the file will only be copied if it is an absolute path. It means starts with '/' on Unix or drive letter or network drive on Windows. Method (2) doesn't check it and just copy the file. In our case to the working directory as the file name is not prefixed with anything.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. `file.transferTo(file1.toPath());` works.

`transferto(File file)` and `transferto(Path path)` both exists. Interestingly, `transferto(File file)` does not work for some reason.

Comment: Yes. File is from the "ancient" Java package java.io Path is from the new one java.nio.file Anyway thanks for feedback.

Comment: For me, both works. I also checked the source code, it is very odd. the difference in the two functions are kind of funny. But Both functions works.

Comment: @Popeye probably different Java versions? I'm on Java 20

Comment: @Mar-Z please check other conditions. I do not see anything suspicious in Springboot source code. I am using java-19. But that's not a good reason to assume old functions broke.

Comment: @Mar-Z I tried using both Java 20 and 17, `transferto(File file)` does not work in both.

Comment: Yes. Please check the updated answer. @Popeye we are not assuming anything - we are testing :)

Comment: Thank you, solved my issue on Java 8 spinning on Weblogic 14c.

Answer (score 2):

I did a little digging on the source code itself to find out why this is happening.

In the class `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest` two functions exists

```java
        @Override
        public void transferTo(File dest) throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
            this.part.write(dest.getPath());
            if (dest.isAbsolute() && !dest.exists()) {
                FileCopyUtils.copy(this.part.getInputStream(), Files.newOutputStream(dest.toPath()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void transferTo(Path dest) throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
            FileCopyUtils.copy(this.part.getInputStream(), Files.newOutputStream(dest));
        }
    }
```

Definition of `part.write()` method is written in class `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart`

```
    @Override
    public void write(String fileName) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        // testing whether the path is absolute or not, OP's code is relative path
        if (!file.isAbsolute()) {
          // HIGHLIGHTED PART
            file = new File(location, fileName);
        }
        try {
            fileItem.write(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }
```

In the `write` method absolute path is being created by using `location` variable. Variable `location` hold the value of `ROOT` directory of `TOMCAT` as example

```
/tmp/tomcat.8080.12533880900101227658/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT/
```

So, when you do not give an absolute path to `write`, function simply decide to move the file to `ROOT` directory. In other word, file is being moved, working properly, **OP just does not know where to look for the moved file.**

What can be done to resolve OP''s issue.

```java
class ControllerClass {
  // Create an absolute base path where your uploaded file will be moved. 
  // All file will be moved here 
  private final String uploadFilePath = "/a/suitable/path/";
  @PostMapping("/form3")
  public String handleFormUpload3(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
      String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
      File file1 = new File(uploadFilePath, fileName);
      //if(!file1.exists())
      //    file1.createNewFile();
      file.transferTo(file1);
      System.out.println(file1.exists());
      return "redirect:uploadSuccess";
  }
}
```

**PS**
This is poor judgement of coding by Spring Boot development team. They have overwridden function that has different behvior. This is bad principle for writing library. It is unwise to force programmer to be hyper aware of how functions with same name behave. It just create distrust towards the library. Both of the functions should have behave exactly the same. My apporach would be simpley call the other function with proper value instead of writing a whole new function with different nature.